# Make the modal transparency background absolutely transparent.

Tags: apache-flex, background, transparency

I am using the below given code to try to make the transparency 0, but I still am unable to make the background become absolutely transparent.

```
<mx:Style>
        global {
            modalTransparencyBlur: 0;
            modalTransparency: 0.0;
            modalTransparencyColor: black;
            modalTransparencyDuration: 0;
        }
    </mx:Style>
```

How can I fix this.

Regards
Zee

Comment: You want to make the transparency of "what" to 0?  Show more of your code.  I would suspect that local styles override any global settings.

Comment: +1 copy/pasted your code and it's perfectly transparent, so the style must be overridden somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the backgroundAlpha to 0? 
backgroundAlpha is a property of your modal component, rather than a css style. 
See here for some backgroundAlpha examples:
[Flex Examples: backgroundAlpha](http://blog.flexexamples.com/tag/backgroundalpha/)

Also, a useful tool for playing around with styles and visual properties is FlexSpy.  It's a lot like Firebug, in that you can modify styles and properties in real time while your app is running.  Download here: [FlexSpy](http://code.google.com/p/fxspy/)