# Change background bluriness when calling Alert or PopupManager

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, alert, blur, flex4.5

In Flex 4.5 is there please a way to control how blurred is background when displaying an [Alert](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Alert.html) or [PopupManager.addPopUp()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html)?

I have playing cards displayed on the background of my game, when displaying a modal popup window with possible bids to the user and can't blur the cards too much (because the player should see them before deciding what to bid).

Comment: Someone answered your question by asking another one, just a minute ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153624/make-the-modal-transparency-background-absolutely-transparent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a clearer statement of the idea provided in the linked post above: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/14/changing-a-modal-alert-controls-blur-transparency-and-transparency-color/